# Define function to classify records within a df and adding new columns. Pandas dfs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of about 20 dfs and I want to clean the data for analysis. 
Can there  be a function that loops through all the dfs in the list & performs the tasks below, if all the columns are the same?

Create a column [time_class] that classifies each as arrival time as "early" or "late" by comparing with the [appt_time] column. Next I want to classify each record as "early_yes", "early_no", "late_yes" and "late_no" in another column called [time_response]. This column would check the values of [time_class], [YES] and [NO]. If a record is 'early' and '1' for yes then the [time_response] column should say "early_yes" Then a frequency table to count the [time_response] occurrences. the frequency table headers will be from the [time_response] column.

How can I check to make sure the time columns are reading as times in pandas? 
How can I change the values in the yes and no column to 'yes' and 'no' instead of the 1's?

each df has this format for these specific columns:

```
    Arrival_time    Appt_Time  YES   NO
    07:25:00        08:00       1
    08:24:00        08:40       1
    08:12:00        09:00            1
    09:20:00        09:30            1
    10:01:00        10:00            1
    09:33:00        09:30       1
    10:22:00        10:20            1
    10:29:00        10:30       1
```

I also have an age column in each df that I have tried binning using the cut() method, and I usually get the error that the input must be one dimensional array. Does this mean I cannot use this method if the df has other columns other than just the age?

How can you define a function to check the age column and create bins grouped by 10 [20-100], then use these bins to create a frequency table? Ideally I'd like the freq table to be columns in each df. I am using pandas.

Any help is appreciated!!

UPDATE: When I try to compare arrival time and scheduled time, I get a type error TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: What dtype are the "Arrival_time" and "Appt_Time" columns? This is a good starting point to decide how best to compare the two columns.

Comment: they are datetime.

<class 'datetime.time'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps you get started - you'll see that there are a few useful methods like `replace` in pandas and `select` from the numpy library. Also if you want to apply any of the code to multiple dataframes that are all in the same format, you'll want to wrap this code in a function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

### this code helps recreate the df you posted
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Arrival_time": ['07:25:00', '08:24:00', '08:12:00', '09:20:00', '10:01:00', '09:33:00', '10:22:00', '10:29:00'], 
    "Appt_Time":['08:00', '08:40', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '09:30', '10:20', '10:30'],
    "YES": ['1','1','','','','1','','1'],
    "NO": ['','','1','1','1','','1','']})

df.Arrival_time = pd.to_datetime(df.Arrival_time, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df.Appt_Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Appt_Time, format='%H:%M').dt.time
### end here

# you can start using the code from this line onward:
# creates "time_class" column based on Arrival_time being before Appt_Time
df["time_class"] = (df.Arrival_time <= df.Appt_Time).replace({True: "early", False: "late"})

# creates a new column "time_response" based on conditions
# this may need to be changed depending on whether your "YES" and "NO" columns
# are a string or an int... I just assumed a string so you can modify this code as needed
conditions = [
    (df.time_class == "early") & (df.YES == '1'),
    (df.time_class == "early") & (df.YES != '1'),
    (df.time_class == "late") & (df.YES == '1'),
    (df.time_class == "late") & (df.YES != '1')]
choices = ["early_yes", "early_no", "late_yes", "late_no"]

df["time_response"] = np.select(conditions, choices)

# creates a new df to sum up each time_response
df_time_response_count = pd.DataFrame({"Counts": df["time_response"].value_counts()})

# replace 1 with YES and 1 with NO in your YES and NO columns
df.YES = df.YES.replace({'1': "YES"}) 
df.NO = df.NO.replace({'1': "NO"})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Arrival_time Appt_Time  YES  NO time_class time_response
0     07:25:00  08:00:00  YES          early     early_yes
1     08:24:00  08:40:00  YES          early     early_yes
2     08:12:00  09:00:00       NO      early      early_no
3     09:20:00  09:30:00       NO      early      early_no
4     10:01:00  10:00:00       NO       late       late_no
5     09:33:00  09:30:00  YES           late      late_yes
6     10:22:00  10:20:00       NO       late       late_no
7     10:29:00  10:30:00  YES          early     early_yes

>>> df_time_response_count
           Counts
early_yes       3
late_no         2
early_no        2
late_yes        1
```

To answer your question about binning, I think np.linspace() is easiest to create the bins you want.

So I'll add some random ages between 20 and 100 to the df:

```
df['age'] = [21,31,34,26,46,70,56,55]
```

So the dataframe looks like this:

```
df
  Arrival_time Appt_Time  YES  NO time_class time_response  age
0     07:25:00  08:00:00  YES          early     early_yes   21
1     08:24:00  08:40:00  YES          early     early_yes   31
2     08:12:00  09:00:00       NO      early      early_no   34
3     09:20:00  09:30:00       NO      early      early_no   26
4     10:01:00  10:00:00       NO       late       late_no   46
5     09:33:00  09:30:00  YES           late      late_yes   70
6     10:22:00  10:20:00       NO       late       late_no   56
7     10:29:00  10:30:00  YES          early     early_yes   55
```

Then use the value_counts method in pandas and with the bins parameter:

```
df_age_counts = pd.DataFrame({"Counts": df.age.value_counts(bins = np.linspace(20,100,9))})
df_age_counts = df_age_counts.sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df_age_counts
                Counts
(19.999, 30.0]       2
(30.0, 40.0]         2
(40.0, 50.0]         1
(50.0, 60.0]         2
(60.0, 70.0]         1
(70.0, 80.0]         0
(80.0, 90.0]         0
(90.0, 100.0]        0
```

Comment: Thank you! This works when I test it on one df. I will try it on a few dfs in a loop.

Is there maybe a way to combat the ages column?

Comment: Awesome! If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If I have some time, I might also help with the binning question you asked about.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: When I try to compare arrival time and scheduled time, I get a type error
`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.time'`